# Geting SharePoint 2010 Multiline Field Value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am getting multine content type filed value programatically with LINQ To SharePoint. It shows like below

```
<div class=\"ExternalClass282872C28A554849AA9167214C968756\"><p>​<a href=\"/_layouts    /listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={9E248748-4423-4259-9D2C-0A052742660F}&amp;ID=5&amp;ContentTypeID=0x010005F5F3E297E77B439FAEB4658DFAAA6A\"><font color=\"#003759\">

   **MyDesired Value**

</font></a></p></div>"
```

How can i get only value `MyDesignedValue` from this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sphttputility.convertsimplehtmltotext.aspx)

For more information see, [Fetch a list item to a MultiLine textBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410127/fetch-a-list-item-to-a-multiline-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

```
string MyString = “<div class=\”ExternalClass282872C28A554849AA9167214C968756\”><p><a href=\”/_layouts    /listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={9E248748-4423-4259-9D2C-0A052742660F}&amp;ID=5&amp;ContentTypeID=0x010005F5F3E297E77B439FAEB4658DFAAA6A\”><font color=\”#003759\”>MyDesired Value</font></a></p></div>”;

String result = Regex.Replace(MyString, @”<[^>]*>”, String.Empty);
```